# Need help in json grouping query

Tags: mysql, json

My current code:

```
create table Messages (
  id int,
  userId int,
  message varchar(255)
);

insert into Messages
values 
  (1, 1, 'Message u1_1'),
  (2, 1, 'Message u1_2'),
  (3, 2, 'Message u2_1'),
  (4, 2, 'Message u2_2'),
  (5, 3, 'Message u3_1')
;

select
  json_object('Messaging info',
    json_object(
      'id', userId,
      'user', json_object( 
        'messages', json_arrayagg(
          json_object(
            'message', message,
            'msgId', id
          )         
        )
      )
    )
  )
from Messages
where userId in (1, 2)
group by userId
```

This query returns 2 records that I cannot group into one json object.
In other words: i want to merge this

```
{"Messaging info": {"id": 1, "user": {"messages": [{"msgId": 1, "message": "Message u1_1"},{"msgId": 2, "message": "Message u1_2"}]}}}
```

and this

```
{"Messaging info": {"id": 2, "user": {"messages": [{"msgId": 3, "message": "Message u2_1"}, {"msgId": 4, "message": "Message u2_2"}]}}}
```

into

```
{
  "Messaging info": {
    "id": 1,
    "user": {
      "messages": [
        {
          "msgId": 1,
          "message": "Message u1_1"
        },
        {
          "msgId": 2,
          "message": "Message u1_2"
        }
      ]
    },
    "id": 2,
    "user": {
      "messages": [
        {
          "msgId": 3,
          "message": "Message u2_1"
        },
        {
          "msgId": 4,
          "message": "Message u2_2"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Tried to play with `json_arrayagg` at topmost of query, but got a grouping error.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rjmkqmM5AvvPDAXbzrTBNY/1

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do `json_arrayagg` in the outer query

```
SELECT json_object('Messaging info',json_arrayagg(ad))
FROM(
  select
    json_object(
      'id', userId,
      'user', json_object( 
        'messages', json_arrayagg(
          json_object(
            'message', message,
            'msgId', id
          )         
        )
      )
  ) as ad
from Messages
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rjmkqmM5AvvPDAXbzrTBNY/2